# How to find links to other Excel workbooks when a search on the linked file names fails?

Tags: microsoft-excel, links

When I first built my Excel 2016 workbook, I used links to other workbooks. Then at some step, I performed a copy/past by values to suppress the links.

But when I open the workbook, Excel unexpectedly still warns me for these linked workbooks, arguing the links could not be updated because the linked workbook was not recomputed before saving - I translate so it may be not exactly the English wording used by Excel you are used to.

Of course, I have performed a `search` in all the workbook, by formula, for the name of the linked workbooks, even part of it, and nothing has been found by Excel.

In the `Data/Modify links` menu, the dialog box lists all the linked files and it is here, but I cannot find a mean to localize where the links are in the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down the problem:

- You have a Workbook (Book1) which have many broken links to other workbooks (Book2, Book3 etc).
- You *know the names* of the *linked files* (workbooks) by going to `Data>Edit links`
- Now, you need to find a way to locate the cells in the current workbook (Book1) that have a link to other workbooks (Book2 and Book3)

For the reproduction of this problem, I have made two workbooks - Book1 and Book2.

Here is the **Book1** and it is the current workbook where I need to locate the cells containing those links to another workbook.

[image]

*(Such a huge number of cells and I need to identify the ones which have links to another Workbook)*

Going to `Data>Edit Links` give me this:

[image]

Now, *note down* the source, in my case it is *Book2*.

This means that I have a link to *Book2* in the current workbook *Book1*. I need to identify those *particular* cells in this *Book1*.

**So, here we go:**

- Press `Ctrl+H` to go to *Find and replace* option in *Book1*.
- In `Find what`, type the *workbook name* that you obtained from `Data>Edit Links` - in my case, it is **[Book2]**
- Click `Options`
- Leave `Replace with` **blank**. Click on corresponding `Format`. After clicking, `Replace Format` menu comes up. Then go to `Fill>Background Color` and choose any color and click `OK`. I have chosen Red.
- In `Within`, select `Workbook`
- Search: `By Rows`
- Look in: `Formulas`

If you did everything right, final *Find and Replace* option will look like this:

[image]

Now, click `Replace All`.

And there they are, all the cells *that contained a link to `Book2`*, will appear there in Red:

[image]

Now, do whatever you want to do with those cells.

Do the same thing again to identify the links to other Workbooks (Book3, Book4 etc.) but change the *Background Colour* to something other than Red and *Find what:* to `Book3`.

And that's it. I hope this helps. Do tell how it does :)

Comment: Thanks @Sanu_012, but that's what I did and explained, and Excel finds nothing

Comment: "In the Data/Modify links menu, the dialog box lists all the linked files and it is here, but I cannot find a mean to localize where the links are in the workbook" - if this's correct, then results should reflect inevitably :|

Comment: Actually, that's the problem: files supposed to be linked appear in the __Data/Modify links dialog box__, but the search for them fails

Comment: even If it is so, this line doesn't describe that - "In the Data/Modify links menu, **the dialog box lists all the linked files and it is here**, I cannot find a mean to localize where the links are in the workbook" :|

Comment: This one does: " I have performed a search in all the workbook, by formula, for the name of the linked workbooks, even part of it, and nothing has been found by Excel"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro that does the same as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> [solution above](https://superuser.com/a/1548871/):

```
Sub findlinks()
Dim sht, c
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Module In ThisWorkbook.Modules
        If sht.Name = Module.Name Then GoTo nextsht: 'Skip modules masquerading as sheets
    Next Module
    For Each c In sht.UsedRange.Cells
        If InStr(1, c.Formula, ".xls", vbTextCompare) > 0 And Left(c.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
            If InStr(1, c.Formula, "\\") + InStr(1, c.Formula, ":\") > 0 Then 'Network path, or mapped/local drive
                Debug.Print "'" & sht.Name & "'!" & c.Address & " " & c.Formula 'Ctrl+G debug window
            End If
        End If
    Next c
nextsht:
Next sht
End Sub
```